# Getting Top10 Users using Google Shets Query and thier Count

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I was attempting to organize and summarize data in Google Sheets by using a Pivot table. The data includes names in Column C and statuses in Column K. My goal is to find the total count and unique count of statuses for each user and only display the top 10 users based on their status count.

Explaining this might be a bit tricky, but it's straightforward to do in Excel Pivot tables. However, in Google Sheets, it's challenging to set up.

I've included a link to the sheet to better show what I'm trying to accomplish. Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

[Sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VZBpnI31uszSCWK7G24YTblLe_Rm3KsdhX1oP8ZbQzM/edit?usp=sharing)

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER('Scheduling Database'!K5:K, 'Scheduling Database'!B5:B<>"")))
```

Comment: Are you looking for a solution via *pivot table*?!

Comment: Yeah if it can be achieve using Query or Pivot Table. I am Ok with both.

Comment: Even if it can be achieve using 2 or 3 formulas then still its perfect, because i do not think a single formula can achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=let(Σ,query({Data!C:C,Data!K:K},"Select Col1, Count(Col1) Where Col1<>'' group by Col1 pivot Col2",1),
     Λ,sortn(hstack(Σ,byrow(Σ,lambda(i,if(ifna(xmatch("blocked",i)),"tots",sum(i))))),11,,columns(Σ)+1,),
     Ξ,vstack(Λ,bycol(Λ,lambda(i,if(ifna(xmatch("*"&"Name",i,2)),"tots",sum(i))))),
       hstack(choosecols(Ξ,1),let(x,transpose(choosecols(Ξ,sequence(columns(Ξ)-2,1,2))),transpose(sort(x,choosecols(x,-1),))),choosecols(Ξ,-1)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the built-in **"hide rows" feature**:

- in the pivot table, select all rows underneath the top 10
- mouse right-click
- from the drop-down menu, select "Hide rows [xx]-[yy]"

Essentially, this collapses the view. If you press the little tringle next to the row numbers, all data is displayed again. This works especially well with smaller datasets.

Hope this helps.